# How to use File Explorer on a rooted device?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Eclipse is connected to my rooted phone and I can run debug sessions and see LogCat messages. I can also see the phone in `Devices` view in the `DDMS` perspective, but: When I open the `File Explorer` view (in same perspective) I see **nothing**.

I could swear that I saw it working once but for the life of me I can't recall if there was anything special that I had to pre-configure on the device-under-debug or Eclipse.

The [Working with an emulator or device's file system](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) on the Android Developer's Using DDMS page says:

> DDMS provides a File Explorer tab that allows you to view, copy, and
>   delete files on the device. This feature is useful in examining files
>   that are created by your application or if you want to transfer files
>   to and from the device.
>
> To work with an emulator or device's file system:
>
> 1. In the Devices tab, select the emulator that you want to view
>      the file system for.
> 2. To copy a file from the device, locate the file in the File
>      Explorer and click the Pull file button.
> 3. To copy a file to the device, click the Push file button on the
>      File Explorer tab.

But... these 3 easy steps don't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

What do I need to do to view files on my rooted device on Eclipse's File Explorer?

1. P.S. `adb pull` works, but I would like to be able to use File
   Explorer, too.
2. P.S. Turning on USB storage (from the notification area) doesn't
   help File Explorer either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse's Android File Explorer not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244318/eclipses-android-file-explorer-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File explorer in DDMS works fine with real devices. Just use the **stand alone** one, not the Eclipse plugin.

From the command line, type `ddms.bat`, then select the (real) device, and only then select Device > File Explorer from the menu:

[image]

Comment: Apparently ddms.bat is now deprecated, so you should use monitor.bat