# Eclipse's Android File Explorer not working

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've had a look around the web for an answer to this with no joy.

In my Eclipse (Helios) in DDMS mode I can't use the file explorer tab for looking at files on my device.
If I start up an emulator it work fine but for my device its blank. 
I'm using CM7 on a HTC Desire

The closest to an answer was [here](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/30765-solved-ls-command-for-eclipse-file-explorer/) but I'm not sure if its really a solution. I'm a bit wary.

Comment: YOu have to root your phone for that

Comment: It is rooted (using CM7). But I shouldn't need root anyway for file explorer to work. So I'm wondering it is actually a CM7 issue

Comment: Tim, that sounds like exactly the solution. CM7's ls command does not have sorting, copying an AVD's toolbox and re-linking ls worked for that guy, did you try it?

Comment: yep... just did that (see answer below) .. . I initially thought there was an `ls` command already and I was afraid to mess with it. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved.

I actually looked into `/system/bin` on the device and noticed there was no `ls` in the first place so I put a symbolic link in to `toolbox` (like how its set up in the emulator) and it works now.

In detail:

- Reboot device into ClockworkMod recovery (via Rom Manager)
- Mount /system via ClockworkMod options
- In a terminal on your computer connect to the device with `adb shell`
- `cd /system/bin`
- `ln -s toolbox ls`
- `reboot`

And now I can see the files

Comment: I had to copying "toolbox" from emulator and linking "ls" to it. See details instructions here: solved by copying "toolbox" from emulator and linking "ls" to it  NOTE: Follow exact instructions, especially don't miss the "chmod +x toolbox" part

Comment: @tamsler please edit your comment so the url works. Click on the 'help' link to see how to include hyperlinks. thanks

Comment: I'm using galaxy S2 with MIUI-GALNET mod. Although I've followed everything stated in the link and also in this answer, File Explorer still remain blank. ADB have no problem detecting my device, it's just the file explorer that is not showing anything.

Comment: here is more detailed tutorial: [http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/30765-solved-ls-command-for-eclipse-file-explorer/]

Comment: My rooted viewsonic gtab not able to boot after above steps, crashes after boot animation and stops (it's runing in Adams honeycomb)

Answer (score 0):

Just close the emulator and execute again.