# android debug on the pad how can I export the APP data

Tags: android, debugging, virtual-machine

When I debug on the virtual Machine use Eclipse, I can easily watch the data using DDMS perspective. but how could I get data when I debug on the real machine. Does everyone has a better idea or a solution. Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, there is a "Device" tab.

Under the "Devices" tab, assuming you already have you device connected via a usb, you can highlight your device.

After doing so, you can use the "File Explorer" tab to look at the data (directories/files) within your connected device.

Now if this appears blank for you, take a look at the post below:

[How to use File Explorer on a rooted device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433761/how-to-use-file-explorer-on-a-rooted-device)

If it is not blank then, you should be able to debug your data from the "File Explorer" tab.

Database Files (sqlite):

If you are wondering where `/data/` files are stored, DDMS does not have permissions to view these files.

One approach is to use

`sqlite3 /data/data/dev.client.android/databases/your_database_name.db`

when in debugging mode.

You can also use `adb pull` to retrieve the database file.

Getting the absolute path of your database can be done with

```
File myDbFile = getDatabasePath(YOUR_DB_NAME);
Log.i(myDbFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I had found the files in attach on real machine in eclipse.but where does my app.db file exists?

Comment: in ddms-> file explorer you can see your all data

Comment: Check my updates about database files. It should be helpful :)

Comment: another question, how can I get the root permission to the real device

Answer (score 0):

In DDMS perspective in Eclipse, there is a "Device" tab
if you not able to see it then go in WINDOWS option then choose SELECT VIEW in this select DEVICE

go in device tab and and u can see here all listing of attach device select your real device now you can see your all logs of real device :)