# Cordova resolveLocalFileSystemURL callbacks not fired

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I've been trying to run the following code but the callbacks [ok() and ko()] are not called.
Using Worklight 6.2 (Cordova 3.4).

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            success, fail);

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory
            + "www/index.html", ok, ko);
}

function ko(e) {
    alert("NO");
}

function ok(fileEntry) {
    alert("OK");
}
```

On the other hand `requestFileSystem` callbacks are called regularly.

Comment: Can you updated the question with the fuller code snippet that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet in the question will not work in Android due to a Cordova defect: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7273.

To progress further, it would help to understand what are your plans for the file itself.

- Do you simply want the path to the file
- Or do you want to alter the contents of the file?
- Or?

You can read more about file system operations in Cordova in this question/answer: [Where does LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT point to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399465/where-does-localfilesystem-persistent-point-to)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to access local fiiles in *Worklight* running an *Android* environment using a `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
//Works only on Android
function prendiCaricaRisorsaWorklight(percorsoPiuNomeFile) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var risposta = "";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4
                && (xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.status == 0)) {
            risposta = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            alert(risposta); 
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "file:///android_asset/www/default/"
            + percorsoPiuNomeFile, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Usage example:

```
prendiCaricaRisorsaWorklight("css/cssInterno.css");
prendiCaricaRisorsaWorklight("js/jsInterno.js");
```

This shows on *Android* an alert with the file content.